# How to join two JavaScript arrays of JSON Objects, without using JQUERY?

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, join

I have two arrays of objects (If I am not using proper terminology, please forgive me.  I am new to JS).  The arrays `dataset` and `dataset2`, have objects with a common key `id`.  I want to merge each object to form a new array of merged objects.  As shown in `datasetCombined` below.

```
dataset = [{​
    "State": "AL",
    "id": 1000,
    "name": "Alabama",​​
    "percent_educated": 24},

    {​
    "State": "AL",
    "id": 1001,
    "name": "Autauga County",​​
    "percent_educated": 24.6},

    {​
    "State": "AL",
    "id": 1003,
    "name": "Baldwin County",​​
    "percent_educated": 29.5
    }]

dataset2 = [{​
    "id": 1000,
    "qualified_professionals": "64,767,787",​​
    "high_school": "58,820,411",
    "middle_school_or_lower": "27,818,380" },

    {
    "id": 1001,
    "qualified_professionals": "783,076",​​
    "high_school": "1,009,593",
    "middle_school_or_lower": "496,036" },

    {​
    "id": 1003,
    "qualified_professionals": "8,968",​​
    "high_school": "12,519",
    "middle_school_or_lower": "4,528" 
    }]
```

Desired Output:

```
datasetCombined = [{​
    "State": "AL",
    "id": 1000,
    "name": "Alabama",​​
    "percent_educated": 24,
    "qualified_professionals": "64,767,787",​​
    "high_school": "58,820,411",
    "middle_school_or_lower": "27,818,380"},

    {​
    "State": "AL",
    "id": 1001,
    "name": "Autauga County",​​
    "percent_educated": 24.6,
    "qualified_professionals": "783,076",​​
    "high_school": "1,009,593",
    "middle_school_or_lower": "496,036"},

    {​
    "State": "AL",
    "id": 1003,
    "name": "Baldwin County",​​
    "percent_educated": 29.5,
    "qualified_professionals": "8,968",​​
    "high_school": "12,519",
    "middle_school_or_lower": "4,528"
    }]
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Add property from one array into another array with the same key (javascript)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52668966/add-property-from-one-array-into-another-array-with-the-same-key-javascript)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After the blunder with misreading your question I spent a bit of time and built this example for you to merge the two arrays based on the Id.

```js
let dataset = [{
    "State": "AL",
    "id": 1000,
    "name": "Alabama",
    "percent_educated": 24
  },
  {
    "State": "AL",
    "id": 1001,
    "name": "Autauga County",
    "percent_educated": 24.6
  },
  {
    "State": "AL",
    "id": 1003,
    "name": "Baldwin County",
    "percent_educated": 29.5
  }
];

let dataset2 = [{
    "id": 1000,
    "qualified_professionals": "64,767,787",
    "high_school": "58,820,411",
    "middle_school_or_lower": "27,818,380"
  },
  {
    "id": 1001,
    "qualified_professionals": "783,076",
    "high_school": "1,009,593",
    "middle_school_or_lower": "496,036"
  },
  {
    "id": 1003,
    "qualified_professionals": "8,968",
    "high_school": "12,519",
    "middle_school_or_lower": "4,528"
  }
];

// create a function to reduce your arrays
let reducer = function(accumulator, currentValue, currentIndex, array) {
   // check if the item already exists in the array
 let found = accumulator.find((item) => item.id == currentValue.id);
  
  if (found) {
    // if it exists then use assign to merge the two values
    Object.assign(found, currentValue)
  } else {
    // doesn't exist, just add it to the array
   accumulator.push(currentValue);
  }
  
  return accumulator;
}

let datasetCombined = [];

dataset.reduce(reducer, datasetCombined);
dataset2.reduce(reducer, datasetCombined);

console.log(datasetCombined);
```

Answer (score 2):

A possible solution to the above problem could be:

```
Object.assign(b, a);
```

This way b would have both its own properties and a‘s properties. However, we might want to avoid modifying b. In such a case, we can introduce a new, empty object and copy properties from a and b to it.

```
const c = Object.assign({}, a, b);
```

And If for some reason you cannot use ES6 language features in your application, you can resort to using the Lodash library.

```
const c = _.assign({}, a, b);
```

Comment: when I output this to the consol.log  I get  an Object {   }  is there any way I can get an array of objects back [  ] ?

Comment: I tried the same in chrome browser console and i got the output, please try below code snippets:


const a = {
  name: "John",
  age: 23
};
const b = {
  job: "Analyst"
};

const c = Object.assign({}, a, b);

type c in console and you will get result as {name: "John", age: 23, job: "Analyst"}

Answer (score 1):

You could use Array.prototype.reduce:

```
const datasetCombined = dataset1.reduce((acc, next) => {
    const combinedItem = Object.assign(
        {},
        next,
        dataset2.find(item => (item.id = next.id))
    );
    acc.push(combinedItem);
    return acc;
}, []);
```

Answer (score 1):

You could look for the `id` and append an existing object or push a copy of the object to the result set.

This works for an arbitrary count of arrays.

```js
var dataset = [{ State: "AL", id: 1000, name: "Alabama", percent_educated: 24 }, { State: "AL", id: 1001, name: "Autauga County", percent_educated: 24.6 }, { State: "AL", id: 1003, name: "Baldwin County", percent_educated: 29.5 }],
    dataset2 = [{ id: 1000, qualified_professionals: "64,767,787", high_school: "58,820,411", middle_school_or_lower: "27,818,380" }, { id: 1001, qualified_professionals: "783,076", high_school: "1,009,593", middle_school_or_lower: "496,036" }, { id: 1003, qualified_professionals: "8,968", high_school: "12,519", middle_school_or_lower: "4,528" }],
    result = [dataset, dataset2].reduce((r, a) => {
        a.forEach(o => {
            var temp = r.find(({ id }) => o.id === id);
            if (!temp) {
                r.push(Object.assign({}, o));
            } else {
                Object.assign(temp, o);
            }
        });
        return r;
    }, []);
    
console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

A slightly better approach with a [`Map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map).

```js
var dataset = [{ State: "AL", id: 1000, name: "Alabama", percent_educated: 24 }, { State: "AL", id: 1001, name: "Autauga County", percent_educated: 24.6 }, { State: "AL", id: 1003, name: "Baldwin County", percent_educated: 29.5 }],
    dataset2 = [{ id: 1000, qualified_professionals: "64,767,787", high_school: "58,820,411", middle_school_or_lower: "27,818,380" }, { id: 1001, qualified_professionals: "783,076", high_school: "1,009,593", middle_school_or_lower: "496,036" }, { id: 1003, qualified_professionals: "8,968", high_school: "12,519", middle_school_or_lower: "4,528" }],
    result = Array.from([dataset, dataset2].reduce(
        (r, a) => a.reduce((m, o) => m.set(o.id, Object.assign(m.get(o.id) || {}, o)), r),
        new Map
    ).values());
    
console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this with [Underscore.js](https://underscorejs.org/) or [Lodash](https://lodash.com/)

```
var mergedList = _.map(dataset1, function(item){
  return _.extend(item, _.findWhere(dataset2, { 
    id: item.id 
  })); 
});
```

Comment: You should specify this is using a third party library and which one.

Comment: Noted. Thanks @alexander

Answer (score 0):

If you are not using `ES6` and you don't want to use any library like `Lodash`,
and If The number of objects in both arrays are equal and they are in order by the `id` property (as shown in your example), then you can use the code bellow:

```
var datasetCombined = [];

dataset.map(function(obj,keyNo){
  for (var key in dataset2[keyNo]){
    obj[key]=dataset2[keyNo][key];
  }
  datasetCombined.push(obj)
});
```